# How to scroll images horizontally in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiscrollview

I have an imageview called "cardImgView" in that I want to load two images by scrolling horizontally, I have tried the following way, in this case I can able to scroll only to up and down and the images also not changing, anyone
 have idea how to do this correctly.

```
let img: UIImage = self.dataDict.object(forKey: kCardImgFront) as! UIImage
let img2:UIImage = self.dataDict.object(forKey: kCardImgBack) as! UIImage
imgArray = [img, img2]        

for i in 0..<imgArray.count{           
    cardImgView?.image = imgArray[i]                        
    scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
    scrollView.addSubview(cardImgView!)
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: The content size width of `cardImgView` must be equal to the width of your scrollview and then add `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1) is wrong.

Comment: scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: common image size * CGFloat(i + 1), height: common image height)

Comment: @ElTomato I changed as u suggested but, not working still

Comment: and it is showing second image in the array only

Comment: You are showing only **one** `UIImageView` - your `cardImgView`... each time through the loop you are simply replacing the image in that view with the next image. If you want to see two images, you need two `UIImageView` objects.

Comment: @DonMag can u explain a bit, how can I do with two imageView objects

Comment: @iVJ - see my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified my code and tried as follows and its working now. with page contrlller

```
   let imgArray = [UIImage]()
   let img: UIImage = self.dataDict.object(forKey: kCardImgFront) as! UIImage
   let img2:UIImage = self.dataDict.object(forKey: kCardImgBack) as! UIImage

   imgArray = [img, img2]        
   for i in 0..<imgArray.count { 

let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = imgArray[i]                        
let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 
self.scrollView.frame.width + 50, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)
scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

 }

self.scrollView.delegate = self

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){

pageController.currentPage = Int(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / 
  CGFloat(4))
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

First, as I commented, you are currently using a single `UIImageView` --- so each time through your for-loop you are just replacing the `.image` of that one image view.

Second, you will be much better off using auto-layout and constraints, instead of trying to explicitly set frames and the scrollView's contentSize.

Third, `UIStackView` is ideal for your use case - adding multiple images that you want to horizontally scroll.

So, the general idea is:

- add a scroll view
- add a stack view to the scroll view
- use constraints to make the stack view control the scroll view's contentSize
- create a new `UIImageView` for each image
- add each image view to the stack view

Here is a simple example that you can run in a Playground page to see how it works. If you add your own images named image1.png and image2.png to the playground's resources, they will be used (otherwise, this example creates solid blue and solid green images):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// UIImage extension to create a new, solid-color image
public extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a UIScrollView
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()

        // we will set the auto-layout constraints
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // set background color so we can see the scrollView when the images are scrolled
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .orange

        // add the scrollView to the view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        // pin scrollView 20-pts from top/bottom/leading/trailing
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

        // create an array of empty images in case this is run without
        // valid images in the resources
        var imgArray = [UIImage(color: .blue), UIImage(color: .green)]

        // if these images exist, load them and replace the blank images in imgArray
        if  let img1: UIImage = UIImage(named: "image1"),
            let img2: UIImage = UIImage(named: "image2") {

            imgArray = [img1, img2]

        }

        // create a UIStackView
        let stackView = UIStackView()

        // we can use the default stackView properties
        // but can change axis, alignment, distribution, spacing, etc if desired

        // we will set the auto-layout constraints
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add the stackView to the scrollView
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        // with auto-layout, scroll views use the content's constraints to
        // determine the contentSize,
        // so pin the stackView to top/bottom/leading/trailing of the scrollView
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        // loop through the images
        for img in imgArray {

            // create a new UIImageView
            let imgView = UIImageView(image: img)

            // we will set the auto-layout constraints, and allow the stackView
            // to handle the placement
            imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            // set image scaling as desired
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleToFill

            // add the image view to the stackView
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(imgView)

            // set imgView's width and height to the scrollView's width and height
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true

        }

    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am trying to use with page controll and my cardImgView is already there in storyboard scene

Comment: Tip: when you post a question, describe what you are really trying to do - more likely to get proper help. You can still use the information I gave you - the fundamentals are there. However, if you want to use page control, you should look at `UIPageViewController` ... almost all of the work would already be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a proper frame for the cardImgView. It would be something like

```
cardImgView.frame = CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
```

Finally, after the for loop, you need to set scroll view's content size:

```
scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * imgArray.count
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting error msg when i tried use the CGFrame in this code

Comment: Can you provide some code and exact errors you're getting, please? If cardImgView is a UIImageView instance it's frame property shouldn't be read-only.

Comment: that cardImgView is a JBAsyncImageView type

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'CGFrame' this msg I am getting

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a typo. It's CGRect, not CGFrame. Will change the code

Answer (score -1):

I have written scrolling images horizontally in swift. Please check with this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var Bannerview: UIView!
    var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
    var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
    var loadinglabel: UILabel = UILabel()

    var nextPage :Int!
    var titlelab :UILabel!
    var bannerimg :UIImageView!
    var scroll :UIScrollView!
    var viewPanel :UIView!
    var pgCtr:UIPageControl!
    var bannerArr:[String]!

    var imgUrlstr :NSString!

    var screenSize: CGRect!
    var screenWidth: CGFloat!
    var screenHeight: CGFloat!

    func uicolorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32)->UIColor
    {
        let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
        let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
        let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0

        return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1.0)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        screenWidth = screenSize.width
        screenHeight = screenSize.height

        bannerArr = ["image1.jpeg","image2.jpeg","image3.jpeg","images4.jpeg","images5.jpeg"]

        self.bannerview()

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```